# Python Iteration Efficiency

Tags: python

How do I make this code more efficient?  I don't want to keep repeating the if statement for each state and just want one function or chunk of code. In the beginning of this code I have a dictionary array with a key and value pairing of each of the 50 states with their corresponding sales tax.  How can I make a function that pulls from each key?

```
if state == 'Alabama':
    state = state_taxes['Alabama']
    tax = state * meal
    total = meal + tax + tip
    print "Your total is: $" + "%.2f" % total
elif state == 'Alaska':
    state = state_taxes['Alaska']
    tax = 0
    total = meal + tax + tip
    print "Your total is: $" + "%.2f" % total
elif state == 'Arizona':
    state = state_taxes['Arizona']
    tax = state * meal
    total = meal + tax + tip
    print "Your total is: $" + "%.2f" % total
```

etc., etc., etc..........

Comment: Well, why are you repeating the code? Hint: what differs between each version of the code? What's the pattern to the differences?

Answer (score 6):

Why the if statements at all?  Can't you just do:

```
state_tax = state_taxes[state]
tax = state_tax * meal
total = meal + tax + tip
print "Your total is: $" + "%.2f" % total
```

Comment: i guess `tax` varies on state.

Comment: @salmanwahed -- Yes, but that all gets taken care of by the `state_taxes` dict. . .

Answer (score 1):

Many states have complex tax rates. Some have [higher alcohol tax](http://www.taxpolicycenter.org/taxfacts/displayafact.cfm?Docid=349) for example.

You can have a nested dict of dicts for multiple data items:

```
>>> state_taxes={
...     'Alabama': {"Rate": 0.04}, # etc
...     'Alaska': {"Food Rate": 0.08, "Alcohol Rate": 0.21}
...     # etc...
... }
```

Then access hierarchically:

```
>>> state_taxes['Alabama']['Rate']
0.04
```

So you can do:

```
tax=(state_taxes['Alaska']['Food Rate']*food_cost + 
     state_taxes['Alaska']['Alcohol Rate'] * drink_cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `state_taxes` dictionary contains floats that align with the tax for each state (for example in your code you have 'Alaska' returning 0 for tax rather than computing it with what is presumably a state tax of 0 for Alaska from the `state_taxes` dictionary). From there you don't need to use the `if` statement at all, you can simply look up the value of the tax. Note that is also best practice to not overwrite your `state` variable with a different type of value (in your example you first use `state` to represent the name of the state, then use `state` to the tax for that state).

```
state = 'Alabama' #or 'Alaska', or whatever you set this to
state_tax = state_taxes[state]
tax = state_tax * meal
total = meal + tax + tip
print "Your total is: $" + "%.2f" % total
```

Note that this assumes your state will always be in your `state_taxes` dictionary. You will want to add some error handling if there is any chance your state variable will have a value that is not in the keys of `state taxes`